# Magnific popup video runs on background issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup

I am trying to make on my website a video with Magnific popup video but when you click outside the box or click on X button it start playing sound in background, I cannot see a solution online and here is my code.

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="bg-screen">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#videostory" class="vid-button" id="videolink">watch video <i class="pl-4 fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
        <div id="videostory" class="mfp-hide" style="max-width: 75%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cezsFi_522M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript CODE :

```
$('#videolink').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    midClick:true,
});
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? Also after cleaning your HTML code, I found that there is and extra `</iframe>` tag there. Not sure if that is the problem, but you should remove it from your HTML as different browsers may behave wonky

Comment: i didn't get any errors in my HTML and also when i removed the <iframe> tag the problem still presents :(

Comment: I asked if you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: there is no errors in browser console , also when i click on video when it opens the console shows this : Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "file:///C:/Users/megam/Desktop/myProject/vidtut.mp4". , when you click on JS.main it shows you magnific source code .

Comment: Is there any reason you are using iframe? The way you are using this plugin is different than what's described [in its documentation](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)